# nginx disable tls v1.0 & v1.1 not working

Tags: php, nginx, tls1.2

I am trying to disable tls v1.0 and tls v1.1 on my websever through nginx but when I test tls using [tls checker](https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test), it does not work and still shows tls v1.0 & v1.1 are enabled.

Below is my `nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name test.mydomain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    #
    server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name test.mydomain.com;
        include self-signed.conf;
        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";
        
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the result of tls checker:

[image: enabled tls]

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Check the files under `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` if there are additional `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1` settings.

Comment: /etc/nginx/conf.d directory is empty

Comment: In case you use Letsencrypt/Certbot, see if you have this file `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf`.

Comment: letsencrypt is not being used

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? Not reloaded, _restarted_. Are you behind a proxy or CDN?

Comment: just realized that there is an AWS WAF running in front of nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was an AWS Web Application Firewall running in front of nginx web server. Removing TLS v1.0, v1.1 from there fixed the issue.